# Tag specfiles seems ambiguous, how to proceed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-wiki, tag-disambiguation

The [specfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specfiles) seems ambiguous to me. The excerpt from the tag Wiki states

> A structured text file that provides build and installation information for a software to be packaged in an RPM with the rpmbuild command.

And the [actual tag Wiki entry](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/specfiles/info) states

> Specfiles are the files that tell the [rpm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpm) and [rpmbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpmbuild) programs which are the sources for one (or more than one) package, how to build, with which dependencies, where to install, additional scripts to execute on install/uninstall and so on.
>
> Spec files are usually distributed within SRPM files, which contain the spec file packaged along with the source code.

However, the GCC driver [also knows Spec Files](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.4/gcc/Spec-Files.html) to control the behavior of the backend tools (e.g. `cc1`, `collect2`). Same name, completely different scope.

It would seem to me (but I'm no tag expert) that it would make sense in a question to give either [specfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specfiles) *along with* [rpmbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpmbuild) **or** [specfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specfiles) *along with* [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc) to avoid ambiguity.

However, the tag Wiki still refers to just one particular use (RPM). And old some old questions may not have [rpmbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpmbuild) but may have [rpm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpm) or perhaps there are some that already used the tag in the GCC sense.

While GCC calls them "Spec Files" the suffix is commonly `.specs`, so adding [specsfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specsfiles) or something like [gcc-specs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc-specs) (or [gcc-specfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc-specfiles)) could be an option. Of course the former may create confusion with the existing [specfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specfiles). Last but not least one could split the tag into two and create [gcc-specfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc-specfiles) and [rpmbuild-specfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpmbuild-specfiles) or similar.

So this is why I turn to the community to ask: how to proceed with a tag whose name could refer to multiple topics, but currently only one of these topics is covered according to the tag Wiki.

Thanks!

Comment: Historically, the community has made specific tags for this sort of thing (programmer pedantry being what it is).  I personally prefer the additional tags, but it is what it is.

Comment: As there are just 35 questions, feel free to retag them into the correct tags, creating new tags as needed. The two tag approach seems fine to me.